# iOS App made with Unity crashes, when loading a scene while loading an admob video ad

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash, admob

i have made an iOS App with unity and uses Video Ads with Admob. When a video loads an the player switch the scene by an button, the game crashes in the moment, when the video is loaded.

Is there a way to stop loading the video when the player wants to switch the scene?

Kind regards

Comment: Can u provide some code sample?

Comment: This is the code is used for the video promotion:
https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded-ads
But when i switch the scene, before video is loaded, the app crashes.